# Parsing individual parts of an xml file from WebService - Android

Tags: java, android, web-services

I'm trying to parse the sunrise and sunset time from this [webservice](http://www.earthtools.org/sun/52.77431872/-1.20639/4/12/99/0) and display them into two separate textviews.

I've been trying to follow this tutorial but I'm struggling to understand how to adapt it:
http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-xml-parsing-tutorial/

In that example the xml file has parent and child nodes and loops to collect them all, in my example I just want to grab two specific parameters and be able to display them.

This is the code I currently have, at the moment it calls the webservice and display the full xml file in an EditText. I need to work out how parse the individual values rather than all of it.

```
      package com.authorwjf.http_get;
      import java.io.IOException;
      import java.io.InputStream;
      import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
      import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
      import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
      import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
      import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
      import org.apache.http.protocol.BasicHttpContext;
      import org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext;
      import android.app.Activity;
      import android.os.AsyncTask;
      import android.os.Bundle;
      import android.view.View;
      import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
      import android.widget.Button;
      import android.widget.EditText;

public class Main extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    findViewById(R.id.my_button).setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.my_button);
    b.setClickable(false);
    new LongRunningGetIO().execute();
}

private class LongRunningGetIO extends AsyncTask <Void, Void, String> {

    protected String getASCIIContentFromEntity(HttpEntity entity) throws IllegalStateException, IOException {
       InputStream in = entity.getContent();
         StringBuffer out = new StringBuffer();
         int n = 1;
         while (n>0) {
             byte[] b = new byte[4096];
             n =  in.read(b);
             if (n>0) out.append(new String(b, 0, n));
         }
         return out.toString();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
        String finalURL = "http://www.earthtools.org/sun/52.77431872/-1.20639/4/12/99/0";
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(finalURL);
        String text = null;
        try {
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet,
                    localContext);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            text = getASCIIContentFromEntity(entity);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return e.getLocalizedMessage();
        }
        return text;
    }   

    protected void onPostExecute(String results) {
        if (results!=null) {
            EditText et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.my_edit);
            et.setText(results);
        }
        Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.my_button);
        b.setClickable(true);
    }
}
}
```

I've been attempting to sort this for a while now and I'm about ready to give up, if anybody could help me out and show me some working code to grab the sunset and sunrise times that would be amazing.

Thanks for looking x

Comment: You deleted your previous question when I almost finished writing the answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an XML DOM parser, because it is the easiest.

You should send your `results` text to the XML parser using `DocumentBuilderFactory` and then request various values such as sunset and sunrise from the parser.

I suggest following this tutorial: [Android XML Parsing Tutorial – Using DOMParser](http://www.androidpeople.com/android-xml-parsing-tutorial-%E2%80%93-using-domparser)

---

**Sunrise Example** (pseudo-code... *very* pseudo-code):

```
NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("Morning");
Node node = nodeList.get("sunrise");
String sunrise = node.getValue();
```

Comment: The problem I have is that all the examples I find online have repeating pattern in the XML file, whereas this one has several layers all with different parents:
http://www.earthtools.org/sun/52.77431872/-1.20639/4/12/99/0 --- How do I select only Sunrise and Sunset values when they are under different parents

Comment: For each of the two values `sunset` and `sunrise` you must separately follow the path through hierarchical `nodes` and `values` and sometimes even `attributes`. Best method is to capture and printout the response XML and then taylor your code one node/branch at a time until you have traversed down the specific branches you need to get the data you want.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-sax-parser/

http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-dom-parser/

You can choose between Sax parser or w3c dom parser.

The above has tutorials on the same.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
String lsunrise,sunset;
String xml=    "<sun >"+
"<version>1.0</version>"+
"<location>"+
"<latitude>52.77431872</latitude>"+
"<longitude>-1.20639</longitude>"+
"</location>"+
"<date>"+
"<day>4</day>"+
"<month>12</month>"+
"<timezone>0</timezone>"+
"<dst>0</dst>"+
"</date>"+
"<morning>"+
"<sunrise>07:45:31</sunrise>"+
"<twilight>"+
"<civil>07:05:54</civil>"+
"<nautical>06:22:57</nautical>"+
"<astronomical>05:41:56</astronomical>"+
"</twilight>"+
"</morning>"+
"<evening>"+
"<sunset>16:02:28</sunset>"+
"<twilight>"+
"<civil>16:42:03</civil>"+
"<nautical>17:24:58</nautical>"+
"<astronomical>18:05:57</astronomical>"+
"</twilight>"+
"</evening>"+
"</sun>";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    parse();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}
  void parse()
   { try 
        {

    SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
    SAXParser saxParser = factory.newSAXParser();
    InputSource is = new InputSource();
    is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xml));
    DefaultHandler handler = new DefaultHandler() {


     boolean sr=false;
     boolean ss=false;


    public void startElement(String uri, String localName,String qName, 
                Attributes atts) throws SAXException {

        //System.out.println("Start Element :" + qName);

        if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("sunrise")) {
            sr=true;
        }

        if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("sunset")) {
            ss=true;
        }



    }

    public void endElement(String uri, String localName,
        String qName) throws SAXException {

        //System.out.println("End Element :" + qName);

    }

    public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length) throws SAXException         
        {
        if (sr) {
            System.out.println("FSun rise: " + new String(ch, start, length));
            sr = false;
        }

        if (ss) {
            System.out.println("Sun set : " + new String(ch, start, length));
            ss = false;
        }


    }

     };

       saxParser.parse(is, handler);

     } catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
     }


    }
  }
```

Outputs snrise and sunset. Modify the above accordingly to get other tag values.

Answer (score 0):

While it's not the "easiest" or "quickest" implementation for parsing XML code, I've always preferred to use the SAXParser utilities from Android.

A great tutorial to follow that breaks everything down step by step [is from tutsplus.com](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk-build-a-simple-sax-parser/)

Answer (score 0):

Edit: please see this related question. [Parsing sunrise and sunset values from web service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15711607/parsing-sunrise-and-sunset-values-from-web-service/15711814?noredirect=1#comment22315434_15711814)

You can parse the xml and set the values to the view.
Check out this [tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-dom-parser/).

```
import java.io.StringReader;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;

//here's your xml string.
String test = "<sun xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation=\"http://www.earthtools.org/sun.xsd\"><version>1.0</version><location><latitude>52.77431872</latitude><longitude>-1.20639</longitude></location><date><day>4</day><month>12</month><timezone>0</timezone><dst>0</dst></date><morning><sunrise>07:45:31</sunrise><twilight><civil>07:05:54</civil><nautical>06:22:57</nautical><astronomical>05:41:56</astronomical></twilight></morning><evening><sunset>16:02:28</sunset><twilight><civil>16:42:03</civil><nautical>17:24:58</nautical><astronomical>18:05:57</astronomical></twilight></evening></sun>";
try {

        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        InputSource s = new InputSource(new StringReader(test)); 
        Document doc = dBuilder.parse(s);

        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

        Log.v("Root element :" + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());

        NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("morning");

        Log.v("----------------------------");

        for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {

            Node nNode = nList.item(temp);

            System.out.println("\nCurrent Element :" + nNode.getNodeName());

            if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

                Element eElement = (Element) nNode;

                System.out.println("sunrise : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("sunrise").item(0).getTextContent());

            }
        }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
```